# Valgrind possibly lost message when checking for memory leaks - C

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, bmp

I'm doing a course at the moment and one task is to create a program to resize 24 bit bitmap images by modifying some code they provide (which simply copies an image). The resizing itself was not a problem, but when I run a memory leak check with Valgrind I keep getting the message below. I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm going wrong and would appreciate some pointers (pun definitely intended) as to where the leak is, but nothing more.

Also, if you could let me know how good my code is, or ways I could improve at programming in general it would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Valgrind message]

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./copy n infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember factor and filenames
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    char* infile = argv[2];
    char* outfile = argv[3];

    // check if scale factor is valid (i.e. between 1 and 100)
    if ((n < 1) || (n > 100))
    {
        printf("Invalid scale factor, enter value between 1 and 100 inclusive\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // open input file 
    FILE* inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 3;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE* outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 4;
    }

    // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // create headers for outfile
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfout = bf;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER biout = bi;

    // change output's header info w.r.t. n, the scale factor
    biout.biWidth *= n;
    biout.biHeight *= n;
    biout.biSizeImage *= n * n;
    bfout.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + 
                   sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 
                   biout.biSizeImage;

    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 || 
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 5;
    }

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bfout, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&biout, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // determine padding for scanlines
    int paddingIn = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) % 4)) % 4;
    int paddingOut = (4 - (biout.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) % 4)) % 4;

    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {
        //create buffer and set to row's pixels
        RGBTRIPLE* buffer = malloc(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
        fread(buffer, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), bi.biWidth, inptr);

        // for each infile scanline, copy n times
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            // iterate over pixels in scanline
            for (int k = 0; k < bi.biWidth; k++)
            {   
                // copy pixel n times
                for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
                    fwrite(&buffer[k], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);

            }

            // then add padding to Outfile (if needed)
            for (int k = 0; k < paddingOut; k++)
                fputc(0x00, outptr);

        }

        // move past padding on infile
        fseek(inptr, paddingIn, SEEK_CUR);

        // free the buffer
        free(buffer);
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

    // that's all, folks
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what arguments you used to compile your code?

Comment: @jayant If you intend to reproduce, you'll also need "bmp.h"

Comment: @Kotshi At this stage I just want to ensure that the code was compiled with debugging symbols `-g`

Comment: You should call your program with `./resize`, otherwise you will call `resize` from your linux system.

Comment: @mch You should have use answer as you found the solution.

Comment: I wonder, why you did not notice, that the output produced by calling `resize` does *not at all* match what your code outputs ... :-/

Comment: Please don't post raster image screen shots of textual output of Linux utilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are analysing [resize](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html), which is a binary executable on your system.

If you call a program without `./` in front of it, the shell will search for a program with this name in every directory which is entered in the `PATH` variable (`echo $PATH` to see it), but not in the current directory.

You have to call your program with `./resize`, so it will look in the `.` directory (your current directory) and will start your program.

The output `Usage: resize [-u] [-c] [-s [rows cols]]` does not match your code.

Comment: Nitpicking: Although typically invoke via a shell, `resize` *is not* a shell-command, but a simple binary executable.

Comment: @alk thanks, I have added some informations. I did not know what `resize` is, it could also be a script file or so.

Comment: Thanks @mch! Worked perfectly, no memory leaks!